Expose message property in Dropwizard health functionality?
Registered Health Checks are returned on localhost:8081/healthcheck, and include a message property:
{
  "worker-alive": {
    "healthy":false,
    "message":"I am not alive failure count =2",
    "duration":0,
    "timestamp":"2024-05-08T11:26:15.079Z"
  }
}

When I configure that health check using the Health  functionality, that health check is returned on localhost:8080/health-check?name=all&type=ALIVE, however, it does not include the message property:
[
  {
    "name":"worker-alive",
    "healthy":false,
    "type":"ALIVE",
    "critical":true
  }
]

I believe the this response is generated via these classes:

ScheduledHealthCheck
HealthStateView
JsonHealthResponseProvider

Is there a way to make the response from localhost:8080/health-check?name=all&type=ALIVE include the message property?
